# Вынести часть кода хтмл-страницы в отдельный файл?

Tags: javascript, html, файлы

Итак, есть у меня кусок хтмл-кода, например:

```
<p class="text">Hello, my friend!</p>
```

И таких элементов может быть ОЧЕНЬ МНОГО, так, дабы не засорять основной хтмл-файл, возникла у меня мысль, что надо бы весь этот "текст" вынести в отдельный файл, а затем подключать его по необходимости через скрипты.
На просторах интернета нашел вот такое решение своей проблемы:

1. Создаем файл, например, "1.js"
2. В созданном файле пишем:

```
document.write('
<p class="text">Hello, my friend!</p> 
<p class="text">Hello, my friend!</p> 
<p class="text">Hello, my friend!</p> 
...
');
```

3. Далее идем в основой файл и в нужном месте просто прописываем путь к файлу через скрипт:

```
<body>
  <div id="prologue">
    <script src="./js/1.js"></script>
  </div>
<\body>
```

Но в итоге ничего не происходит.
Консоль выдает следующую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Атоме функция "document.write()" вся красная, вместо того, чтобы "write" подсвечивать голубым... Итак, я снова нуждаюсь в помощи экспертов по таким делам. Что я делаю не так?

Конечный результат должен быть похож на выполнение вот такого кода:

```
<body>
  <div id="prologue">
   <p class="text">Hello, my friend!</p>
  </div>
<\body>
```

Попробовал добавлять код по одной строке, в итоге консоль хрома выдала следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Строка красная - вообще ни о чем не говорит. Код работает да/нет? Если нет, какие ошибки есть в браузере. Если работает, но не так, как ожидалось, опишите, как работает и как надо.

Comment: Код вообще не работает. По задумке, при выполнении этого кода, на страницу браузера должен вывестись текст "Hello, my friend!" со всеми заданными стилевыми параметрами, словно он является частью кода основной страницы-хтмл. Это чтем-то похоже на функцию: только функция выполняет какие-то действия, а здесь просто нужно сохранить кусок кода, а затем вставить его в нужном месте в том виде, в каком он сохранен.

Comment: так а в чем проблема использовать шаблонизаторы

Comment: У вас синтаксическая ошибка в js. Откуда в вашей строке слеши? И как миниму в конце идет завершение строки, а затем очередной слэш...

Comment: SwaD, в смысле "завершение строки" и "очередной слеш"? Вы про '\n'? Слеши были в оригинальном примере кода, что я нашел в интеренте, так что я решил, что это часть его синтаксиса. Я пробовал разные варианты, со слешем, без него, с точкой-запятой, но ни в какой из вариантов не сработал.

Comment: Вот начало `write('\` - зачем слэш тут? Далее идут html теги и в конце строкт опять \. Одинокий символ \ не является разметкой html. Далее в конце у вас `'\);` т.е. завершение строки ' и далее слэш...

Comment: SwaD, я думал, что это часть синтаксиса такая. Но даже убрав слеши, проблема не исчезла.

Comment: Кушайте слона по частям. Напишите для начала `document.write('<p>hello</p>')` и посмотрите на поведение. Далее усложняйте

Comment: SwaD, судя по всему, проблема в чтении синтаксиса хтмд-тегов вроде "<" и ">", но я не понимаю, что не так, так как по идее начиная с открывающей кавычки и до закрывающей кавычки система должна все воспринимать, как сплошной текст... Что идет не так? Непонятно. Думал, что проблема в теге разрыва строки </br>, но даже если его убрать, проблема не исчезает.

Comment: Тут очень большую роль играет несколько моментов. HTML статичная страница? Изначально в вашем примере скрипт пытаеться вставить HTML в страницу, а не из стороннего файла как вы хотите. Будет ли скрипт встраивать HTML в DOM по какой то логике, или он тоже будет статичен? Решения будут разными! И если вы хотите вставить в конкретное место его нужно указать

Comment: SwaD, попытался добавлять по одной строке за раз, в результате, консоль хрома начала ругаться на обычные слова... Скрин добавил к описанию проблемы.

Comment: Freqnsy, не совсем Вас понял, что значит: "скрипт пытаеться вставить HTML в страницу, а не из стороннего файла". Как определить: является файл статичным или динамичным? Насколько я понимаю, мой файл сроиться один раз и сразу, но я активно использую яваскрипты, чтобы публиковать в нем различные переменные (и если я все правильно понимаю, то это уже динамика)

Answer (score 0):

если память не изменяет, в js *символ новой строки*(перенос) очень любит, как бы это... "всплывать из кавычек". а после, интерпретатор веселья ради, любезно подрубает нам **автозавершение строк**, ну т.е. трансформирует наш перенос в оператор завершения строки ";" та да! ¯\(ツ)/¯

```js
document.write('>
< здесь(между символами больше\меньше) стоит перенос, удалите его и... ощутите разницу =) ');
```

Comment: puffleeck, два момента. 1. Я пробовал все записывать в одну строку - это не помогло. Система все равно ничего не видит и не печатает. 2. Есть какой специальный символ, который указывает интерпритатору, что это не конец строки, чтобы не превращать всю запись в сплошную строку?

Comment: можно попробовать экранировать переносы слэшами(ставить слеш прямо перед переносом), либо использовать текстовый аналог `вместо` него: "\n" или "/n". что опять же изуродует все. можно кстати поиграться с косым апострофом(на qwerty под кнопкой ё). если не поможет, тогда только закрывать ковычку перед переносом и конкатенировать следующий кусок...

Comment: puffleeck, и все же это какие-то очень уж кривые костыли (если вообще сработает)... Неужели за все время развития отрасли программирования ни у кого не возникало подобной проблемы? Должно же быть какое-то решение, если человеку нужно разбить свой код на несколько отдельных частей, а затем собрать их вместе.... Просто потенциально обьемы данных которые будут так храниться просто огромны и играть с кодированием каждой отдельно взятой строкой как-то не очень хочеться. Хочется взять кусок кода, запихнуть его в файл, а затем по достать его по первому требованию без лишних заморочек :)

Comment: @drakoblack, "\n" точно работает, проверено `костыли` экранирование вполне стандартный метод родом из регулярок кажется. `ни у кого` ну... document.write артефакт из прошлого века в буквальном смысле. его забыть надо а не чинить. трогать автозавершение = поломать кучу того кода, который приспособлен к нему. в конце концов есть проблемки и поважнее. `разбить свой код` называть **html верстку** кодом, это таки перебор. верстать настолько серьезным образом уже давно не актуально. еще лет 10 назад была генерация верстки, серверная, щас вообще клиентская. почитайте про `html ~шаблонизаторы`